# How to stop memory leak when using ListView in .net maui

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, maui

im new in .net and i create maui app, but i hit the wall (memory leak of ListView ( i think is listview but idk so i give all codes interacting with it)).
Im try search fix or something, but i got nothing.

ListView xml code

```
            <ListView x:Name="ListViewInput" 
                 Grid.Row="2"
                 Grid.RowSpan="4"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                  Margin="0,20,0,0" 
                  BackgroundColor="red"
                  ItemSelected="ListViewInput_ItemSelected"
                  CachingStrategy="RecycleElementAndDataTemplate"
                  >

            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid RowDefinitions="100*"
                              ColumnDefinitions="60*,80*,80*,100*,100*,120*,120*,140*,140*,180*,180*">
                    <Label Text="Tier" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=2}"/>
                    <Label Text="Ench" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=3}"/>
                    <Label Text="Map" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{OnPlatform Default=2, Android=3}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=2}"/>
                    <Label Text="Zone" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{OnPlatform Default=3, Android=5}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=1}"/>
                    <Label Text="Type" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{OnPlatform Default=4, Android=6}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=1}"/>
                    <Label Text="Start time" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{OnPlatform Default=5, Android=7}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=2}"/>
                    <Label Text="End time" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{OnPlatform Default=6, Android=9}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=2}"/>
                    <Label Text="Curr silver" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="7" IsVisible="{OnPlatform Default=true, Android=false}"/>
                    <Label Text="New silver" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="8" IsVisible="{OnPlatform Default=true, Android=false}"/>
                    <Label Text="Curr IV" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="9" IsVisible="{OnPlatform Default=true, Android=false}"/>
                    <Label Text="New IV" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="10" IsVisible="{OnPlatform Default=true, Android=false}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="100*"
                              ColumnDefinitions="60*,80*,80*,100*,100*,120*,120*,140*,140*,180*,180*">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Tier}" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=2}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Enchant}" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=3}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding MapCost}" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{OnPlatform Default=2, Android=3}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=2}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Zone}" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{OnPlatform Default=3, Android=5}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=1}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Type}" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{OnPlatform Default=4, Android=6}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=1}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding StartTime}" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{OnPlatform Default=5, Android=7}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=2}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding EndTime}" FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=24, Android=14}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="{OnPlatform Default=6, Android=9}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{OnPlatform Default=1, Android=2}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding CurrentSilver}" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="7" IsVisible="{OnPlatform Default=true, Android=false}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding NewSilver}" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="8" IsVisible="{OnPlatform Default=true, Android=false}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding CurrentItemValue}" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="9" IsVisible="{OnPlatform Default=true, Android=false}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding NewItemValue}" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="10" IsVisible="{OnPlatform Default=true, Android=false}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
```

DataBiding c# code

```
 private async void GetDataButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sqldata != null)
        {
            sqldata.Clear();
        }

        sqldata = await database.GetAllRuns();

        for(int i = 0; sqldata.Count-1 >= i; i++)
        {
            var zoneInRun = sqldata[i].Zone;
            var typeInRun = sqldata[i].Type;
            switch (zoneInRun)
            {
                case "0": zoneInRun = "Blue"; break;
                case "1": zoneInRun = "Yellow"; break;
                case "2": zoneInRun = "Red"; break;
                case "3": zoneInRun = "Black"; break;
            }
            switch (typeInRun)
            {
                case "0": typeInRun = "Solo"; break;
                case "1": typeInRun = "Duo"; break;
                case "2": typeInRun = "Group"; break;
            }
            sqldata[i].Type = typeInRun;
            sqldata[i].Zone = zoneInRun;

        }


        if (sqldata != null)
        {
            ListViewInput.ItemsSource = sqldata;
        }


        
    }
```

Builder services code

```
        builder.Services.AddTransient<EnchantCalculatorPage>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<DungeonManagerPage>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<NewRunPage>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<ExistRunPage>();

        builder.Services.AddTransient<DungeonRunDatabase>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<EnchantPricesDB>();
```

GetRuns function

```
        public async Task<ObservableCollection<DungeonRun>> GetAllRuns()
        {
            await Init();

            var list = await Database.Table<DungeonRun>().ToListAsync();

            ObservableCollection<DungeonRun> result = new ObservableCollection<DungeonRun>(list);

            return result;
        }
```

Full DungeonRunDatabase class content

```
  public class DungeonRunDatabase
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

        public DungeonRunDatabase()
        {
        }

        public bool TableExist()
        {

            var tableInfo = Database.GetConnection().GetTableInfo("DungeonRun");
            if (tableInfo.Count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }

        }


        public async Task Init()
        {
            if (Database != null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.flags);
                if (!(TableExist()))
                {
                    var result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<DungeonRun>();
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task<ObservableCollection<DungeonRun>> GetAllRuns()
        {
            await Init();

            var list = await Database.Table<DungeonRun>().ToListAsync();

            ObservableCollection<DungeonRun> result = new ObservableCollection<DungeonRun>(list);

            return result;
        }

        public async Task<DungeonRun> GetRunById(int id)
        {
            await Init();
            var result = Database.Table<DungeonRun>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
            return result;

        }

        public async Task<int> SaveItemAsync(DungeonRun run)
        {
            await Init();
            if (run.Id != 0)
            {
                return await Database.UpdateAsync(run);
            }
            else
            {
                return await Database.InsertAsync(run);
            }
        }

        public async Task<int> DeleteRunAsync(DungeonRun run)
        {
            await Init();
            return await Database.DeleteAsync(run);
        }
    }
```

short video showing problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xa22WEkpGpg

i try changing lifetime in builder services and add clear funtion

```
        if (sqldata != null)
        {
            sqldata.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: And this is a memory leak, because?

Comment: because data was always same, but memory through which the application grows

Comment: Memory growing means nothing, in a garbage collected platform such as .Net. Unless app actually runs low on memory, garbage collector may decide not to run. Bottom line: don't worry about it.

Comment: What is `Database` in `Database.Table<DungeonRun>()`? Can you please post a full [mre] somewhere?

Comment: @GuruStron i edit post, now it shows the whole file with the model

Comment: @Rafalekvx memory usage growing does not mean Memory leak. However, writing random code to fix non-existing memory leaks is the quickest way to get some. Cycle your code, If I see that you really run out of memory, we can talk more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your description, this could be a known issue that being tracked in the link below, you can follow up there.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9162

As the application memory usage just keeps going up endlessly as items are `added` or `removed`. You may simply fix the issue by having a single `ObservableCollection` bound to the `CollectionView` and Clear+AddRange from this collection whenever you need to reload the data. You can refer to [this workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9162#issuecomment-1374444131) for more details.